# Google Colab Unzip error (start of central directory not found . . .)

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
Archive:  /......zip
warning [/......zip]:  267811291 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [......zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Any solution about that error?
I saw same question about 8 months ago and found 0 answer. So I need to ask again.

Comment: found a solution at Stack Exchange that I need to fix zip file by using this  [!zip -FF "....zip" -O '....fixed.zip'] and then I can normally unzip [....fixed.zip] now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.